# NodeJS - process.env.NODE_ENV condition not working when using package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 different databases set up for testing, development and production.

Now I would like my express app to switch between these databases depending on which script I run.

```
These are my current scripts:
 "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=dev && node index.js",
    "test": "mocha --timeout 10000"
  }
```

I am assigning the process.env.NODE_ENV value at the top of the test script like this, and the test script runs fine against the correct DB:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
```

But when I run `npm start`, node does not seem to get the value. For instance on this code:

// DB connection

```
let db;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test') {
  mongoose.connect(config.DB.test, options);
  db = mongoose.connection;
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'dev') {
  mongoose.connect(config.DB.dev, options);
  db = mongoose.connection;
  app.use(morgan('combined'));
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'prod') {
  mongoose.connect(config.DB.prod, options);
  db = mongoose.connection;
  app.use(morgan('combined'));
}

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

I get the `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined` error (while running the same code with the test script connects to the correct DB).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this instead:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=dev node index.js",
```

Remove the `&&`

And I'd like to add a way to handle the env not set too:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev'
```

Then change every refers to `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `env`